# Terminal class called from JFrame class don't have user inputs for a reason

Tags: java, swing, terminal, jframe, user-input

Here  is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Login
{
    static BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static String a, b, c;
    static int d, z, f, g, h, i, k;
    public static void Login()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Login");

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Username: ");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Pin: ");

        JTextField txt1 = new JTextField(8);
        JPasswordField pass1 = new JPasswordField(8);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel FormPanel = new JPanel();

        txt1.setBackground(Color.white);
        pass1.setBackground(Color.white);

        panel1.add(label1);
        panel1.add(txt1);
        panel2.add(label2);
        panel2.add(pass1);

        FormPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,8));
        FormPanel.add(panel1);
        FormPanel.add(panel2);
        FormPanel.add(button1);

        pass1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() 
        {
          public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
          {
            changed();
          }
          public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
          {
            changed();
          }
          public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
          {
            changed();
          }
          public void changed() 
          {
             if (pass1.getText().equals(""))
             {
               button1.setEnabled(false);
             }
             else 
             {
               button1.setEnabled(true);
             }

          }
        });

        txt1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() 
        {
          public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
          {
            changed();
          }
          public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
          {
            changed();
          }
          public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
          {
            changed();
          }
          public void changed() 
          {
             if (txt1.getText().equals(""))
             {
               button1.setEnabled(false);
             }
             else 
             {
               button1.setEnabled(true);
             }

          }
        });

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                frame.hide();

                Body a = new Body();
                a.Body();
            }
        });

        button1.setActionCommand("Open");

        frame.setContentPane(FormPanel);
        frame.setSize(8,9);
        frame.pack();
        frame.show();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

and my Body.java is

```
try
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Working time (hours): ");
                a=dataIn.readLine();
                e=Integer.parseInt(a);

                k=e;
                if(k<8)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYou have worked undertime");
                    g=e * 30;
                    h=g * 500;
                    i=h-200;
                    System.out.print("\nYour payment (per month) is: " +i);
                }

                if(k>8)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYou have worked overtime");
                    g=e*30;
                    h=g*500;
                    i=h+200;
                    System.out.print("\nYour payment (per month) is: " +i);
                }

                if(k==8)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYou have worked ontime");
                    g=e*30;
                    h=g*500;
                    System.out.print("\nYour payment (per month) is: " +h);
                }

                System.out.print("\n\nPress 0 to logout: ");
                c=dataIn.readLine();
                d=Integer.parseInt(c);
            }while(d!=0);
        }

        catch(Exception j)
        {
            System.out.print("\nYou probably need to work for more than an hour to start earning");
        }
```

of course I have `import java.io.*;` and `BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(<arguments>);` but when ever I call the body.java that opens in terminal it won't ask for user inputs, but when I try to execute the body.java it asks for user inputs...
I need help right now...

Comment: Why are you trying to mix a console program with a GUI in such a way? You're far better off going either full console or full GUI since they interact with the user in two diametrically opposite ways.

Comment: okay.. then please tell me how can I do some simple calculations in full GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> okay.. then please tell me how can I do some simple calculations in full GUI?

Again you'll want to avoid trying to mix GUI with console programs since they interact with the user in two very dissimilar ways, and the console can lock up the GUI if you're not careful. Instead consider going all console or all GUI.

If you go all GUI, one possible solution is to create a GUI that is similar to what you're already doing with user name and PIN number:

- Give your GUI JTextFields for the user to input his data.
- Add a "Calculate" JButton
- In the button's ActionListener, extract the data from the JTextFields, convert any Strings to numbers that need converting, calculate your value and display it in another JTextField or JLabel.

---

Other side recommendations:

- Don't call deprecated methods since they're deprecated for a good reason. Instead the Java API will usually tell you what alternatives to use.
- Avoid over-use of static variables and methods, since this leads to rigid code that is difficult to test or enhance.
- Try to give your variables names that have meaning so that your code becomes "self-commenting".
- Your log-in window should be a modal dialog of some type, such as a modal JDialog, not a JFrame, since

  - Closing it will not close the entire GUI
  - It will prevent interacting with the main GUI until it has been fully dealt with.

Comment: yeah I've already done the login thing in GUI

all I need to do, in another class is the calculations because it gives me errors in .getText, I've tried doing some fix that the internet has given me. but non yet have worked out

Comment: P.S. my calculations is in GUI *at first* but then it pissed me off so I changed to Terminal to test something.. and my only problem is when ever the terminal show, it doesn't ask for user inputs..

Comment: @AndrewAngeloBarrientos: There's an important lesson to be learned here perhaps, in that sometimes you don't get fixes from the internet, but instead have to **debug** your program to fix it.

Comment: yeah I've been doing that.. I'm just a beginner.. without book, and I don't like how they write it in books...